# command line - How to listen for keypresses whilst in a input command?

Tags: python, input, command-line-interface, keypress, keyevent

I'm writing a small CLI utility in python for a test here. It's an infinite while loop that keeps an input command running.

Every time a command is inputed, it is added to the commands list, which is initialized empty.

Here's a sample snippet:

```
commands = []
    
while True:
    text = input('Utility > ')
    commands.append(text)
```

How could I watch keypress events whilst in an input command, so if one presses arrow up or arrow down, one could shift though the already inputted commands?

Comment: Have you actually tried pressing the up arrow while at an `input()` prompt?  You may get the behavior you want automatically, depending on the environment your script is running in.  (There's no way to implement this yourself with `input()`, you'd have to use some other method of user interaction such as the `curses` module.)

Comment: Nice. I'll check curses. Thanks for pointing a direction.

Comment: On Windows you can use the [`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#module-msvcrt) module to read all keystrokes. In particular see `kbhit()` and `getch()`.